# Ventanas modales en registros relentizan mucho la carga de la tabla

Tags: php, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo una tabla (datatable de bootstrap) en la que tiene que haber bastantes registros y cada registro tiene dos botones que activan ventanas modales para poder modificar datos o bien mostrar datos enlazados de ese registro en otras tablas.
El tema es que con solo 500 registros la tabla una vez esta operativa tarda bastante (+10 seg.)

Supongo que deriva de que me interesa que este en formato datatable de bootstrap con el paginador y el buscador.

Conoceis alguna solucion?

Comment: Hola Emili, 500 registros no es nada, si demora mucho seguramente es porque estás haciendo alguna consulta SQL que no esta optimizada o estás generando un HTML demasiado grande (_esto puede hacer que el navegador se "congele"_). Sin ver tu código es difícil saber cual es el problema.

Comment: muestra algo de código.  [ask]

Comment: Hola disculpad la demora en contestar, efectivamente @Marcos habia un problema en la consulta ya que no podia ser, he corregido la consulta y ya funciona correctamente. gracias.